# syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Tags: math, operator-keyword, shell

running the below script I receive :

> line 8: ((: i = 0 : syntax error:
>   invalid arithmetic operator (error
>   token is " ")

Any idea what is wrong? Can it be the I edit with text editor on an iMac? something to do maybe with a CR?

```
domains=( yourdomain.com yourdomain2.com )
sqldbs=( yourdb1 yourdb2 )
opath=$HOME/backup/
mysqlhost=mysqlhostname
username=mysqlusername
password=mysqlpassword
suffix=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#domains[@]} ; i++ ))
do
    cpath=$opath${domains[$i]}
    if [ -d $cpath ]
    then
        filler="just some action to prevent syntax error"
    else
        echo Creating $cpath
        mkdir -p $cpath
    fi
    mysqldump -c -h $mysqlhost --user $username --password=$password ${sqldbs[$i]} > ${cpath}/${sqldbs[$i]}_$suffix.sql
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and paste again line 8 (as it was in script) and worked fine. It appears that parsing errors were due an extra character in line 8

Answer (score 1):

The error code is telling you what the problem is: you have an extra space. Line 8 should be:

```
for (i=0; i<${#domains[@]}; i++)
```

Comment: I changes line 8 as adviced and now i received: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 line 8: `for (i=0; i<${#domains[@]}; i++)'

Comment: @Jailbreak, are you using bash or sh?

Comment: the script is mentioned here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mysqldump SHELL=/bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notepad++ go to Encoding > Encode in UTF8 without BOM. Sorry I don't know anything about Mac software.

Comment: Not possible. BOM is the first thing in the file, OP's getting and error on line **8**.